# How to set OverflowStrategy in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Is it possible to set an overflow strategy in Webflux, like one would do for any other Sink? See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.html

The default behaviour appears to be:

> `FluxSink.OverflowStrategy BUFFER` Buffer all
>   signals if the downstream can't keep up. Warning! This does unbounded
>   buffering and may lead to OutOfMemoryError.

I was looking for a way to change this to DROP or ERROR: (see `https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.html`)

Comment: I guess you need this operator https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onBackpressureBuffer-int-reactor.core.publisher.BufferOverflowStrategy-

Comment: WebFlow? dont really understand what you mean

Comment: typo sorry, WebFlux

Comment: @YauhenBalykin that could be applied to the service calls inside the controller method. I was wondering if there's a way to set the behaviour at container level?

Comment: How are you creating the sink, the default, for example, is `ignore` when using a flux processor.

Comment: did you achieve the setting at container level? how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Flux.create`,  to emit values, we can pass `FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.DROP` as an additional parameter.

If you use `EmitterProcessor` /Any processor, the sink method accepts the `OverflowStrategy`.

```
    EmitterProcessor<Object> emitterProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create();
    FluxSink<Object> sink = emitterProcessor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.DROP);

    // you should use sink to publish values
    sink.next(obj);
```

Comment: I'm talking of webflux, how to setup the strategy in the container